# Enable document footer

Tags: html, iis-6, static, footer

I tried to use **Enable document footer** function in IIS6 for my web sites

after some tests i discovered that it works for static files only

may i config it for pages like aspx or asp or maybe u have alternative solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you correctly point out, the IIS Document Footer feature only works with static files.

With ASP you could use include files:

```
<!-- #include file="footer.html" -->
```

The downside is that you'd need to add the include directive to all your ASP scripts.

If you're using ASP.NET you could use a `HttpModule` to inject a header and footer into every page. There's an example of how to do this on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com):

> [Add a header and footer control to all web pages in a web application, using HTTP module](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/headerfooter.aspx)

I downloaded the sample project and it works a treat.